# How to detect that the user has clicked on the screen in a GraphWin?

Tags: python, while-loop, zelle-graphics

I'm trying to learn Python. I need this loop to keep rolling until I click on the screen.

I tried using `win.getMouse` but it's not working.

```
win = GraphWin("game of life", 600, 600)    
win.setCoords(-1, -3, s+1, s+1)

q = True
while q:
    board = iterate(board)
    x = 0
    while x < s:
        y = 0
        while y < s:
            update_color(x, y, board, rec)
            y = y + 1
        x = x + 1
    if win.getMouse():
        q = False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `checkMouse()` instead. It basically checks if the user has clicked anywhere on the screen yet.

```
win = GraphWin("game of life", 600, 600)  
win.setCoords(-1, -3, s+1, s+1)

q = True
while q:
    board = iterate(board)
    x = 0
    while x < s:
        y = 0
        while y < s:
            update_color(x, y, board ,rec)
            y = y + 1
        x = x + 1
    if win.checkMouse() is not None:  # Checks if the user clicked yet
        q = False  # Better to use the break statement here
```

Assuming http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics/node2.html is correct and that the rest of your code is good.

Answer (score 3):

Having True as a condition ensures that the code runs until it's broken by n.strip() equaling 'hello'.

```
while True:
    n = raw_input("Please enter 'hello':")
    if n.strip() == 'hello':
        break
```

[Python docs about `while` loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop)